# How to Layout Widgets Vertically in Flutter Without Overlapping?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I am working on a Flutter project and have encountered a layout issue. As shown in the images below, my current implementation results in widgets being stacked on top of each other, whereas I aim to have them separated vertically.

**Current Layout:**

[image: as you can see, the widgets are stacked]

**Desired Layout:**

[image: The app bar and timer are separated there, not stacked]

How can I separate these widgets vertically within the same view? Specifically, I want to place `HomePageTimerUI` above and `CountDownTimer` below.

Below is the relevant code for my widgets:

***homePageTimerUI.dart:***

```
class HomePageTimerUI extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePageTimerUI({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePageTimerUI> createState() => _HomePageTimerUIState();
}

class _HomePageTimerUIState extends State<HomePageTimerUI> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: double.maxFinite,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            bottom: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(40),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: SafeArea(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TabBar(
                          indicator: const UnderlineTabIndicator(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Color(0xff3B3B3B), width: 4.0),
                              insets:
                                  EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 11.0)),
                          indicatorWeight: 15,
                          indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                          labelColor: const Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                          labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12,
                              letterSpacing: 1.3,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                          unselectedLabelColor: const Color(0xffD7D7D7),
                          tabs: const [
                            Tab(
                              text: "POMODORO",
                              icon: Icon(Icons.work_history, size: 40),
                            ),
                            Tab(
                              text: "SHORT BREAK",
                              icon: Icon(Icons.ramen_dining, size: 40),
                            ),
                            Tab(
                              text: "LONG BREAK",
                              icon: Icon(Icons.battery_charging_full_rounded,
                                  size: 40),
                            ),
                          ])
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: const <Widget>[
              // Center(
              //   child: StartPomodoro(),
              // ),
              // Center(
              //   child: ShortBreak(),
              // ),
              // Center(child: LongBreak()),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

***countDownTimer.dart***

```
class CountDownTimer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CountDownTimerState createState() => _CountDownTimerState();
}

class _CountDownTimerState extends State<CountDownTimer>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController controller;

  String get timerString {
    Duration duration = controller.duration! * controller.value;
    return '${duration.inMinutes}:${(duration.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white10,
      body: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: controller,
          builder: (context, child) {
            return Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    height:
                        controller.value * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                          child: Stack(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              CustomPaint(
                                  painter: CustomTimerPainter(
                                animation: controller,
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                color: themeData.indicatorColor,
                              )),
                              Align(
                                alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                      CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(
                                      timerString,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 112.0,
                                          color: Colors.white),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: [
                          AnimatedBuilder(
                              animation: controller,
                              builder: (context, child) {
                                return FloatingActionButton.extended(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      if (controller.isAnimating)
                                        controller.stop();
                                      else {
                                        controller.reverse(
                                            from: controller.value == 0.0
                                                ? 1.0
                                                : controller.value);
                                      }
                                    },
                                    icon: Icon(controller.isAnimating
                                        ? Icons.pause
                                        : Icons.play_arrow),
                                    label: Text(
                                        controller.isAnimating ? "Pause" : "Play"));
                              }),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}

class CustomTimerPainter extends CustomPainter {
  CustomTimerPainter({
    required this.animation,
    required this.backgroundColor,
    required this.color,
  }) : super(repaint: animation);

  final Animation<double> animation;
  final Color backgroundColor, color;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = backgroundColor
      ..strokeWidth = 10.0
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.butt
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    canvas.drawCircle(size.center(Offset.zero), size.width / 2.0, paint);
    paint.color = color;
    double progress = (1.0 - animation.value) * 2 * math.pi;
    canvas.drawArc(Offset.zero & size, math.pi * 1.5, -progress, false, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomTimerPainter old) {
    return animation.value != old.animation.value ||
        color != old.color ||
        backgroundColor != old.backgroundColor;
  }
}
```

I attempted to solve the issue with a `Column` widget, wrapping both `HomePageTimerUI` and `CountDownTimer`, but it did not work as expected:

```
class StackedPages extends StatelessWidget {
  const StackedPages({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        HomePageTimerUI(),
        CountDownTimer(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

How can I achieve the desired layout as shown in the image below?

[image]

Any guidance or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking for Stack() widget?
You want to replace one for another?
You could use AnimatedSwitcher().

```
AnimatedSwitcher(
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1), child: MyWidget());
```

Where MyWidget() is asigned to the widget you want to show via SetState(). The widgets are switched with a nice animation.

If you need to have one Widget placed one above the other in the vertical axis, you should try to remove the scaffold and the SizedBox with infity values.

Answer (score 0):

if this class can't stack.
Just using `static` type.
add these codes at the same file with `CountDownTimer`.

```
static const Widget countDownTimer = CountDownTimer();
...
// class CountDownTimer
```

Then, you must import this file and call this widget by this parameter.
example

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        HomePageTimerUI(),
        countDownTimer,
      ],
    );
  }
```

but you don't need to use `StackPages` just put `countDownTimer` in your pages.